# Where to put vector layers with different CRS in a PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, vector, spatial-database

We have a PostGIS database with vector data with CRS British National Grid `EPSG:27700`. It is accessed remotely by users with QGIS.

I now need to set up a similar vector layer for Northern Ireland, which has CRS Irish Transverse Mercator `EPSG: 2157`

What things do I need to consider when I am deciding where to put a vector layer with a different CRS in a PostGIS database?

I have had a look at this post relating to raster data, but its very detailed and specific to that particular question [How should I manage PostGIS Raster data with different projections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15005/how-should-i-manage-postgis-raster-data-with-different-projections)

Comment: Separate tables is probably enough, if you are explicity declaring the SRID. Having separate dbs or schemas seems like overkill, when you can easily convert from one projection to the other. Personally, I think schemas are best for separating things that are functionally different -- like postgis functions or data for different users/clients. The SRID for Ireland is 29902 (I think, for what it is worth).

Comment: There are a lot of variables that go into the different table/schema/database/server/host decision, including the volume of data, backup complexity, data security requirements, use patterns, and personal inclination.

Comment: As Vince says, there are a lot of considerations, and it partly comes down to personal inclination. I will attempt to write up a more coherent answer later -- very tied up right now.

Comment: Thanks, I would be very interested to hear what the considerations are. I had thought that it would be a fairly straightforward answer.

Comment: Seconding what John said, absolutely no need for different databases and/or schema just because you have tables with different SRIDs. Just make sure the correct SRID is defined for each table - SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('schema', 'table', 'geom', 27700);

Comment: That's a shame. I just wrote a long answer, but the question has been closed.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll have a read and digest. Not sure I understand why it has been marked to be closed as your answer clearly relates to your 'specific expertise' in the matter and would surely be useful to other questioners.

Comment: There is a general intolerance in Stack Exchange of questions that are regarded as opinion based. I think an answer that gives guidelines is helpful. I understand that a question like is vi better than emacs or Java vs C# would lead to endless flame wars, but I think general rules about somelike like schema usage is on topic.

Comment: Shame, I don't think it's opinion based at all! There is a pretty clear answer here...

Comment: Matt, vote to reopen then :-) I would happily expand on my answer.

Comment: @John can't vote to reopen, not enough rep :(

Comment: Thanks John Powell aka Barça for your concise, ad clear, answer. I have read and re-read over the last couple of days and I have got to say that it makes a lot of sense. Based upon your answer I feel that I have a way forward; you have provided some sound general principles backed up by real world scenarios that make sense.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça - Now this question has been reopened can you make your edit an answer so I can mark it answered. Thanks Martin

Comment: @MartinHügi. Done. I have removed my edits to your question and cleaned up the answer a bit. If anything else occurs to me, I'll add as an edit. I think it is a very good question and one of those things that is non-obvious when you first approach these things. I created our most important table at work, 300Gb and 450 million rows in a table without setting the SRID. This caused quite a lot of pain, until we created enough space to run UpdateGeometrySRID on it. So, do as I say, not as I do :-). Painful mistake.

Comment: @MartinHügi. Btw, I read your profile. I am from the UK, but living in Barcelona for a long time now. I also introduced Postgres/Postgis and QGIS where I work. I am currently preaching about [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com). Check it out, if you haven't already, it is designed for people working on conservation projects, globally, and has huge archives of raster (satellite) and vector and other derived datasets, along with a great code editor and lots of algorithms.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Thanks John. I don't know anything about the Google Earth Engine, so will take a look thanks, and again thanks for the answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules for how to handle datasets with different projections, but here are some general comments on the separate database/schema question.

**Separate databases**

Separate databases are generally used for things that are very functionally different, where you are not likely to want to mix tables from one to the other in a query, for example, client data and static geographic data, would be good candidates to go into different databases. You don't want invoices in the same db as Brazilian trees. This is relevant because there is no built-in mechanism to do joins between tables in different DBs -- you need to use [foreign data wrappers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) (or the older, [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)). Also, note that if you join two tables in separate DBs using foreign data wrappers, currently **indexes will only be used for built-in Postgres types** -- which means no spatial joins (as the spatial objects provided by Postgis are not a native type).

**Different schemas**

Separate schemas within the same database are used for a number of reasons.

1. To separate things that are functionally different. You might want to put 3rd-party extension functions, such as PostGIS in their own schema (this can be useful with backups, see below). This means you are not backing up static data and functions along with dynamic data.
2. To separate data for different users/clients. You can grant access for a user/role to specific schemas, so this can be used for security reason. You can also have a table with the same name but in a differently named schema.
   When you use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) to backup databases or move them to new servers, there is a switch **(-n)** to only include certain schemas. So, if you have static and dynamic data in separate schemas, or different client's data in different schemas, it makes it easy to run partial backups or just move some data to a new machine. This way you can also avoid backing up all the system functions, which will default to the public schema.

There is no reason to need to put British and Irish data, for example, in separate schemas or databases. As the **SRID should always be explicitly set**, there is really nothing to be gained from separating them. You should always set the SRID explicitly on table/column creation, eg,

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (geom geometry (GEOMETRY_TYPE, SRID));
```

or failing that use [UpdateGeometrySRID](https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) to change the SRID. Both of these will update the meta data geometry_columns and prevent queries with functions that accidentally use different SRIDs by giving the  well-known error:

> ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries

And, of course, if you wanted to do a query combining British and Irish grids on tables in the same database, you can always use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) on one of the geometries, but without the pain of having to use foreign data wrappers or dblink.

So to summarize, data you are likely to want to combine in queries should go in the same database. Separate 3rd party (extensions) from your own data. Use schemas according to backup strategies and possibly, to separate tables with the same name, but from different clients.